# Input string was not in a correct format - list from datareader

Tags: vb.net, list

I'm having an issue with outputting results from a list into strings and getting the 'input string was not in a correct format.

```
objConn = New SqlConnection(strConnection)
    objConn.Open()
    objCmd = New SqlCommand(strSQL, objConn)
    rsData = objCmd.ExecuteReader(0)

    If rsData.HasRows Then

        Do While (rsData.Read())

            SubjectNames.Add(rsData.GetString("Subject"))

        Loop

    End If

    rsData.Close()
    objConn.Close()

    Dim first As String = SubjectNames(0)
    Dim second As String = SubjectNames(1)



    html += "<p>" & first & "</p>"
    html += "<p>" & second & "</p>"
```

Now I'm getting the error on the adding to the list line, the subject field in the SP is an all text field and should return a subject name.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong(again!)

Thanks!

Comment: What does your SP return? Does `Subject` allows null values?

Comment: SP returns the header 'Subject' with strings such as Access to HE. It doesn't allow parameters and doesn't allow nulls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give column index of the row instead of column name .

SubjectNames.Add(rsData.GetString(ColumnIndex)) // 0 or 1 or 2

hope this helps

Since GetString() function will accept only index not column name